# Vector potential question

Tags: vector-analysis

If $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are smooth and conservative. Find vector potential $\mathbf{H}$ for $\mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{G}$.

I tried to find it like this (kinda brute force-ishly)

$$\small \begin{align} \nabla \times \mathbf{H}&=\mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{G} \\
\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
H_1 & H_2 & H_3 \end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
F_1 & F_2 & F_3 \\
G_1 & G_2 & G_3 \end{vmatrix} \\
\mathbf{i}\left(\frac{\partial H_3}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial z}\right)-\mathbf{j}\left(\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial H_3}{\partial x}\right)+\mathbf{k}\left(\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial y}\right)&=\mathbf{i}\left(F_2 G_3 - F_3 G_2 \right)-\mathbf{j}\left(F_3 G_1 - F_1 G_3 \right)+\mathbf{k}\left(F_1 G_2 - F_2 G_1 \right)\end{align}$$
so
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\partial H_3}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial z} = F_2 G_3 - F_3 G_2 \\
\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial H_3}{\partial x} = F_3 G_1 - F_1 G_3 \\
\frac{\partial H_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial y} =F_1 G_2 - F_2 G_1 \end{cases} $$
I don't see a simple way to solve $H_1$, $H_2$ and $H_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agh, yes, that's awfully painful. Here's something to try: Since $\mathbf F = \nabla f$ for some potential function $f$, what is $\nabla\times (f\mathbf G)$?

**EDIT:** So, the product rule tells us that $\nabla\times (f\mathbf G) = \nabla f \times \mathbf G + f\nabla\times\mathbf G$. Since $\mathbf G$ is conservative, $\nabla\times\mathbf G=\mathbf 0$, and so, setting $\mathbf H = f\mathbf G$, we have $\nabla\times\mathbf H = \nabla f\times\mathbf G = \mathbf F\times\mathbf G$, as desired.

Comment: $\nabla \times (f \mathbf{G})= (\nabla f) \times \mathbf{G} + f(\nabla \times \mathbf{G})$. But not sure how to apply this.

Comment: Yes, so simplify this!!

Comment: I don't get how simplifying this shows curl $\mathbf{H}$ equals $\mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{G}$ or helps finding $H_1$,$H_2$ and $H_3$.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Once you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it so that the problem will go off the "unanswered" list. :)

Comment: Ahhh now I see. Makes perfect sense! Thanks!